# How to post raw XML in github comment

Tags: xml, github

I am attempting to display some raw xml in a github comment, and I'm buggered if I can get it to show up..
when I paste it and save, the tags are interpreted and I only get content.  But the comment is intended to show what needs to be sent to a third party app.

Here's what I want to insert as comments.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:catalogCategoryTree soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">blablaa</sessionId>
         <parentId xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">?</parentId>
         <storeView xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">?</storeView>
      </urn:catalogCategoryTree>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here's what gets presented to my co-workers

```
soapenv:Header/
soapenv:Body

blablaa
?
?
/urn:catalogCategoryTree
/soapenv:Body
/soapenv:Envelope
```

Is there a way to make what I type show up?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the triple back-tick (```) to multi-line quote code within comments. If you want syntax highlighting, you can also specify the language:

````
```xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
    <soapenv:Header/
    <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:catalogCategoryTreevsoapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
            <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">blablaa</sessionId>
            <parentId xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">?</parentId>
            <storeView xsi:type="xsd:string" xs:type="type:string" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2000/XMLSchema-instance">?</storeView>
        </urn:catalogCategoryTree>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```
````

Comment: Thanks, I ran into the problem that '''<somexml>''' doesn't work. It needs the ``` on seperate lines.